# Как открыть полное изображение при клике на иконку в RecyclerView Android?

Tags: android

Выводятся картинки посредством RecyclerView.

Пока разобрался, как вывести Toast при клике на одну из них.

Нужно показать полноразмерное изображение. Как я понимаю, для этого нужно вызвать новое активити, в котором показать в поле ImageView нужную картинку. Но для этого нужно передать в это активити какой-то идентификатор.

Вот код адаптера:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Album> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Activity activity;
    public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Album> arrayList, Context context) {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        activity = (Activity) context;
    }
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.Title.setText(arrayList.get(position).getTitle());
        String path = Config.img_path + arrayList.get(position).getId();
       Glide.with(activity).load(path).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).error(R.drawable.notfound).into(holder.Thumbnail);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        ImageView Thumbnail;
        TextView Title;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Thumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            Title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.album_title);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    }
}
```

Что нужно указать в методе Onclick?

Comment: Я бы вам предложил открывать новый фрагмент с вашей картинкой.

Answer (score 0):

В можете передать в аргументах активности путь к картинке как String переменную (немного переделал код):

```
  public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageView Thumbnail;
    TextView Title;
    String path;
    Album album;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Thumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        Title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.album_title);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), YourActivity.class);
                   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                   bundle.putString("path", path);
                   intent.putExtras(bundle)
                   startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
     public void bindItem(Album alb){
         album = alb;
         Title.setText(album.getTitle());
         path = Config.img_path + album.getId();
         Glide.with(activity).load(path).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
 .error(R.drawable.notfound).into(Thumbail);
    }

}
```

В методе onBindViewHolder():

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bindItem(arrayList.get(position));
}
```

В методе onCreate() новой активности:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String value = ""; // or other values
if(b != null) value = b.getString("path");
```

И также по ссылке с помощью Glide загружаете фото в большой ImageView.

Ещё есть вариант взять картинку из ImageView, преобразовать в объект Bitmap, затем Bitmap преобразовать в масссив byte[] и также передать его как аргумент активности, затем в активности сделать всё в обратном порядке. Тогда фото не нужно будет загружать снова. Но я не думаю, что это хорошая практика - передавать в аргументах "большие" объекты.

Насчёт этого посмотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8306683/6824996) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4989543/6824996).

Comment: Если через интент передавать больше ~мегабайта, будет исключение. И опечатка value = b.get**String**("path");